# Table caption above, figure caption below

Tags: tables, floats, captions

In a LaTeX article, I would like to place table captions above the tables and figure captions below. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, you can simply use `\caption` before `\begin{tabular}` …

Comment: Yes, just place the `\caption` command directly after `\begin{table}`, and directly before `\end{figure}`.